# How to get object already in store with all its subfield?

Tags: javascript, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to get an object with all its attribute from Apollo store

**Use case detailed**

First query server side:

```
Person {
 id # id=1
 field_A
 field_B
}
```

Second query client side:

```
Person {
 id # id=1
 field_C
}
```

After these queries Apollo store look like that:

```
Person: {
 id # id=1
 field_A
 field_B
 field_C
}
```

Is it possible to get the Person with id=1 and all its attributes without writing a query specifying all fields ? Or readQuery the previous queries and merge the 2 Persons manually ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write the query and you have two options to get this data from your store:

First:
Use the [withApollo HOC](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#withApollo) to get access to your client and then use readQuery passing the query that have all the fields you need.

Second:
Use the query component with the query that have all the fields you need and pass cache-only as the fetch policy. More info here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#graphql-config-options-fetchPolicy

Comment: Ty for your answer. I wasn't sure if it was me missing something or apollo not allowing that without specifying all fields manually.